# Azure Powershell Conversion of Array Object to Hash Table And Related Output Attempt

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am working on creating a Powershell script that will query my Azure Service and find the build number of all my sites based on tags. The main problem I have encountered is that the following:

```
$h = Get-AzureRmTag -Name $Environment -Detailed
```

Seems to return an `Array.Object`. When attempting to convert this Array.Object to a Hashtable using this:

```
$h  | ForEach-Object {$SiteList.Add($_,$inputobject.$_)}
```

When I do this and output my Hash for reviewing, to ensure it works, I get the following:

[image: terminal output]

I am using this output the data:

```
Write-Host ($i | Out-String) -ForegroundColor "green"
```

Here is my full code:

```
# Holder variables to ensure logic works
$myResourceGroup = 'A_Resource_Group'
$ApiVersion = '2015-08-01'
# $Environment = "Primary"

# Initialized Hash tables
$SiteList = @{}
$EvList = @{}
$BuildList = @{}

# Ask user for the environment tag they wish to query.
$Environment = Read-Host "Tag For Query"

# Forms initial object array of data
$h = Get-AzureRmTag -Name $Environment -Detailed 

# converts object to a hash
$h | ForEach-Object {$SiteList.Add($_,$inputobject.$_)} 

# find all the environments inside the larger ones (Everything in Primary)
foreach ($i in $SiteList)
{
    # Check that the output contains desired information
    Write-Host ($i | Format-List | Out-String) -ForegroundColor "green" 

    # Search for the tags under each of the tags saved in $h (Such as all of the sites tagged with Prod)
    $x = Get-AzureRmTag -Name ($i) -Detailed |Format-List
    # save new tags to the $EvList array
    $x | Out-String | ForEach-Object {$EvList.Add($_,$inputobject.$_)}
}

# Go through each sub-tag in $EvList  and find the build number of each
foreach ($a in $EvList)
{
    # Check that the output contains desired information
    Write-Host ($a | Format-List | Out-String) -ForegroundColor "DarkYellow" | Format-List

    # looks for and reads app settings from azure, only keeps buildNumber
    $p = (Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup `
        -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config -Name ($a | Out-String)/appsettings `
        -Action list -ApiVersion $ApiVersion -Force).Properties | Select-Object BuildNumber | Format-List

    # Save each buildNumber to a list containing the site name($a) as the key and the BuildNumber($p) as the value.
    $BuildList.Add($a , $p)
}

# Output the list of sites and buildNumbers in cyan for easy readability
Write-Host ($BuildList | Format-List | Out-String) -ForegroundColor "Cyan"
```

The basic hierarchy of my tags is this:

> Primary ---> Dev, Test, QA, Prod ---> Webjobs, apis, location based web services, ect...

What I'm trying to get is the Build numbers for each of my Webjobs, apis, location based web services, ect... and store them in a list that can be easily formatted and read.

Like this:

[image: goal output]

Currently the second and third foreach loops dont work because they require the first to work but they are there to help keep everything straight and keep the logic all together.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Adding `| Format-List` to your `Write-Host` pipeline is pointless because `Write-Host` does not output anything to the pipeline. Perhaps you mean `Write-Host ($BuildList | Format-List | Out-String) -ForeGroundColor Cyan`?

Comment: While this didnt fix my main issue, @Bill_Stewart, It did help with a much smaller issue i had. So thank you i was trying for the life of me to figure out why that wouldnt change to a list format.

Comment: ForEach-Object processes each object coming down the pipe. Each object is assigned to the variable $_ sequentially in the scriptblock. So you are creating a Hash Key-Value pair where the name is the actual object (which defaults to calling `.ToString()` on the object) and it's value is assigned the value of a variable named $inputObject which as near as I can tell never gets assigned a value.

Comment: @EBGreen, So that section of the code was influenced by [link](https://powershell.org/2013/01/22/convert-powershell-object-to-hashtable-revised/) This website. I was unsure weather the $inputobject variable was necessary or not so i left it in. So if i deleted that variable my hash key-value pair would simply be the name of the object saved as the key and the value set so nothing?

Comment: I don't know if the `.Add()` method on a hash has an overload for one argument or not. What you need to do is identify two properties on those objects. One that is a name or identifier that you want to be the key for each item in the hash and the other that is a value that you want to be the value. Then you could call `.Add()` and reference those properties. Something like: `$h  | ForEach-Object {$SiteList.Add($_,FOO.$_.BAR)} ` where FOO and BAR are the properties.

Comment: So I have 4 "environment" tags assigned under the Primary tag. What im trying to accomplish with this first foreach-object is to get the names of those "Environments" and store them in a hash. So if the value i want is the name of the "Environment" what would I use as my  Key or the 2 properties?

Comment: This is starting to sound like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) problem. What is your end goal? Why do you feel that you need to make a hash?

Comment: There are 2 layers of tags separating me and my the build numbers for each Environment. When i build the prob version I have to find the build number of each environment by hand. I am attempting to automate this process. So the top layer of tags features the one that holds all my Environments it is called Primary. In primary I have Dev, Test, QA, and Prod. In each of these is anywhere between 30 and 100 sites, webjobs, appservices, ect...

Comment: Being fairly new to paowershell scripting what I have learned in the past week is that a Hash (What i understand to be powershells slightly more visual variant on an array) is the best way to accomplish this. It seems that formatting the Array.Object created by the Get-AzureRmTags method is pretty difficult. If a hash table isnt the right way to go please let me know.

Comment: Please edit your question showing examples of the objects that you are working with and describing the results that you expect to see.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but what exactly would you like to get out? A CSV? if so what would it look like? One row per WebObj, API, etc? Or one row per environment with colums for the WebObj, API, etc? What information do you want for each WebObj, API, etc? Just the name? Some unique identifier?

Comment: 'Site     BuildNumber
-------    ----------
site.production1  50.01.03.33
site.production2  50.01.03.33
site.test1    50.02.01.12
site.test2    50.02.01.12
site.dev1    60.01.03.33
site.dev2    60.01.03.33
site.qa1    50.01.03.44
site.qa2    50.01.03.44'

All I want is a big long list just like this (But in cyan) to be displayed in the VSCode powershell cmd window.

Comment: its formatted poorly and i cant comment a picture so ill put it in the answer.

Comment: Please, please, please, edit your question with new information.

Comment: bruh i did. its bellow the code block. there is a big picture of what i want the final output (roughly of coarse) to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Hard coded variable
$myResourceGroup = 'resource'
$ApiVersion = '2015-08-01'

#Initialized Hash table
$SiteList = @{}

#Ask user for the environment tag they wish to query.
$Environment = Read-Host "Tag For Query"

$appServices = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup
foreach ($app in $appServices) 
{
    foreach ($tag in $app.Tags) 
    {
        foreach ($h in $app.Tags.GetEnumerator()) 
        {
            if ($h.Key -eq "Primary" -And $h.Value -eq $Environment) 
            {
                $appName = $app.Name
                $buildNumber = (Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup `
                    -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config `
                    -Name "$appName/appsettings" `
                    -Action list `
                    -ApiVersion $ApiVersion -Force).Properties.BuildNumber

                $SiteList.add($app.Name, $buildNumber)
            }
        }
    }
}

Write-Host ("Primary>") -ForegroundColor "Blue"
Write-Host ("`t" + $Environment + ">") -ForegroundColor "Blue"

Write-Host ("`t`tSite`t`t`t`t`tBuild Number") -ForegroundColor "Blue"
Write-Host ("`t`t____`t`t`t`t`t____________") -ForegroundColor "Blue"
foreach ($h in $SiteList.GetEnumerator()) 
{
     Write-Host ("`t`t$($h.Name):`t`t`t$($h.Value)") -ForegroundColor `
         "Green"
}
```

Alright so this works. Problem solved.